# onLoadEnd is not fired in react-native Image

Tags: reactjs, react-native

hi am trying to load an remote image. onLoadStart is hitting but not the onLoadEnd
`

```
<View style={{ paddingTop: 60, paddingBottom: 10 }}>
              {this.state.loading ? (
                <DotIndicator size={25} color={"white"} />
              ) : (
                <Image
                  resizeMode={this.resizeMode}
                  style={[styles.imageStyle, this.tintStyle]}
                  onLoadStart={e => {
                    this.setState({ loading: true });
                  }}
                  onLoadEnd={e => this.setState({ loading: false })}
                  // defaultSource={NoProfile}
                  //  loadingIndicatorSource={require("@images/profile_placeholder.png")}
                  source={this.userImageUri}
                  onError={error => {
                    this.tintStyle = { tintColor: "lightgray" };
                    this.resizeMode = "contain";
                    this.userImageUri = NoProfile;
                  }}
                />
              )}
            </View>
```

`

**EDIT 1**

*onLoadStart* is hit. *onLoad* is also never being called

does any one have a clue. am new to react. 
Any help is appreciated.
thanks is advance

**SOLUTION**

Since Vignesh and hong mentioned the image is never there so its on loadEnd will never be called. So instead of loading only image or loader I loaded the loader on top of image. Posting this here as it may be useful for someone at sometime. Once again thanks to Vignesh and hong

```
<View
              style={{
                padding: 10,
                width: WIDTH - 50,
                height: WIDTH - 25,
                alignSelf: "center"
              }}
            >
              {this.state.loading ? (
                <MaterialIndicator
                  size={50}
                  color={"red"}
                  style={{
                    marginTop: WIDTH / 2,
                    alignSelf: "center"
                  }}
                />
              ) : null}
              <Image
                resizeMode={this.resizeMode}
                style={[styles.imageStyle, this.tintStyle]}
                onLoadStart={e => {
                  this.setState({ loading: true });
                }}
                onLoad={e => {
                  this.setState({ loading: false });
                }}
                onLoadEnd={e => this.setState({ loading: false })}
                // defaultSource={NoProfile}
                //  loadingIndicatorSource={require("@images/profile_placeholder.png")}
                source={this.userImageUri}
                onError={error => {
                  this.tintStyle = { tintColor: "lightgray" };
                  this.resizeMode = "contain";
                  this.userImageUri = NoProfile;
                }}
              />
            </View>
```

Comment: What is the initial value of ```loading```?

Comment: Probably duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50188373/onloadend-not-firing-in-react-native

Comment: @VigneshVPai initially state is set to false

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's say that the value of `this.state.loading` was `false` before the first render.

When the first render happens, `this.state.loading ?` returns the `Image` component, `onLoadStart` is triggered and `this.state.loading` is set to `true`.

When the second render happens, `this.state.loading` is found to be `true` and `this.state.loading ?` returns the `DotIndicator` component. All the hard work done by the `Image` component during the previous the render is lost. In fact, `Image` component was never present in that context.

Hence, `onLoadingEnd` will never be triggered, because `Image` component never appeared in the second render.

And the `DotIndicator` will forever go round and round and round... Waiting for it's lost love..

Comment: initially the loading state is set to false.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem because I was using a conditional to render EITHER the loading screen OR the image. The solution was to render only the loading screen with a conditional, and to always return the image. Here's a simple example of how I solved it:

```
// this does NOT work -- using a conditional to render the image OR the loading screen will prevent "onLoadEnd" from running
const showLoading = isLoading ? <LoadingScreen /> : <Image source={{ uri: imageUrl }} onLoadStart={() => setIsLoading(true)} onLoadEnd={() => setIsLoading(false)} />

// this DOES work -- return the image AND use a conditional only for the loading screen
return (<>
  {isLoading ? <LoadingScreen /> : undefined} // only use the conditional for the loading screen!
  <Image source={{ uri: imageUrl }}  
      onLoadStart={() => setIsLoading(true)}
      onLoadEnd={() => setIsLoading(false)} />
</>)
```

Comment: Thanks man. Such simple logic can get overlooked!

Answer (score 1):

If `loading` is `true` from the beginning, nothing will be called in the image.

If `loading` value is `false` at first, the image does not see `loadStart` running, only `load` function and `loadEnd` function will be called.

This is because the `loadStart` function runs when the start value is `false` and it is already rendered. And if the start value is `true`, nothing is done because it does not draw an image.

This is a very simple example that you can experiment with:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
state={
 loading: false,
}
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      {this.state.loading ? (
                       <Image
          style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
          source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/tiny_logo.png'}}
        />
              ) : (
        <Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 51}}
          onLoadStart={e => this.setState({ loading: true })}
          onLoad={e => alert("onLoad")}
          onLoadEnd={e => alert("onLoadEnd")}
          source={require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png')}
        />)}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Again thanks for the code. But it doesn't work the way I want it. When I replace the Image with Loader its not working. I came up with a solution have posted it also on my question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying the same image but set its style to width: 1, height: 1. this will always be displayed but is not visible. What this allows is to continue to set the state despite the many rerenders. I then in a if statement have the actual image or a text component that will display image not found. By default NoImageFound is set to true. Here is my code

```
    <Image
      source={{ uri: image }}
      style={{ width: 1, height: 1 }}
      onLoadStart={() => setNoImageFound(true)}
      onLoad={() => setNoImageFound(false)}
    />
    {noImageFound ? (
      <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>No image found</Text>
      </View>
    ) : (
      <View style={styles.icon}>
        <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={styles.image} />
      </View>
    )}
```